# Удаление определенных данных с таблицы по id - RedBean PHP + AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, redbeanphp

Нужно удалить определенный пост по id (пост с уникальным id, в котором есть своя кнопка и при нажатии на неё, этот ОДИН пост - удаляется). В моем случае код работает, но удаляет по id, который я указываю самостоятельно (у меня это пост под номером 1).

Показываю то, что у меня есть:

**index.php**

```
$posts_all = R::findAll('posts', 'ORDER BY -id');
                        
foreach ($posts_all as $posts){
    echo '
    // Тут было много всякой разметки + вывод данных по типу $posts->login
    <button id="post_delete_btn">
        Удалить пост
    </button>';
}
```

**ajax-script.php**

```
$post_del = R::load('posts', 1);
R::trash($post_del);
```

**JS**

```
$('#post_delete_btn').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: '/ajax-script',
        method: 'POST',
        data: $('#post_delete_btn').serialize(),
        success: function(){
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: И вопрос в чем?

Comment: Сейчас с помощью `foreach` пользователю выводятся посты и кнопки с `id="post_delete_btn"`. При нажатии на любую из кнопок на любом посте, удаляется только один пост под номером `1`. А мне надо, что-бы при нажатии на кнопку к примеру поста под номером 3, удалялся пост под номером 3. Если пост под номером 185 то удалялся пост под номером 185 соответственно. То-есть, надо автоматизировать код, который у меня сейчас просто удаляет пост под номером 1. (Разжевал)

Comment: Мне требуется помощь в правке моего одного файла `ajax-script.php`. Всё остальное работает как надо (я про ajax).

Comment: Для того чтобы удалить конкретный пост - его id нужно передать на сервер. То есть: `data: {post_id: 14}`, а на сервере достать ид поста из `$_POST['post_id']`.